# Relative paths error depending on Terminal's current folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos

I've been trying to implement in my scripts that work with files the possibility to run my program regardless of the path the package is located in.
I found that with this code, it would generally work well:

```
import os.path
file_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
data_path = file_path + '/myfile's/path/'
```

If from Terminal I try to execute

```
python3 path/to/my/script/script.py
```

I get no problem. However, if I try to run my script within the current folder it is located in (cd path/to/my/script/) an error shows up. Claiming that /myfile's/path is not a valid directory.
I figured that I could implement the following:

```
 file_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
 if file_path:
    data_path = file_path + '/myfile's/path'
 else:
    data_path = 'myfile's/path'
```

This seems to work out fine, but I wonder if there is a normalized or better way to do this that regards other types of errors I might have not encountered yet.
Thanks ;)

Comment: Excuse the single quotations marks from the /myfile's/path, I just realized I should've declared the string with these " ". hahaha

Comment: Have you tried using [`os.path.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) to create `data_path`? It joins components "intelligently" so it may account for something you're missing by using simple concatenation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not really (this question isnt actually appropriate for SO but here goes)

you need to do this... but when I do i tend to abstract it out

```
def rel_path(*parts):
    BASE = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    return os.path.abspath(os.path.join(BASE,*parts))
```

then I use this function everywhere

```
my_path = rel_path("myfiles","path","example.jpg")
# /path/to/this/file/myfiles/path/example.jpg
```